# Using Navigation Architecture Component with Navigation Drawer

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, android-architecture-components, android-architecture-navigation

I am trying to use the [Navigation Architecture Component](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/navigation/navigation-implementing) (NavHostFragment) with a [Navigation Drawer](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer) (widget.NavigationView). I get one of the following two errors.

1) This can happen when selecting an item from the drawer several times:

`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: navigation destination app.myDomain.navdrawertrials:id/action_rootFragment_to_settingsFragment is unknown to this NavController`

2) This happens from my real code base that is set up the same way as the simplified sample below AFAICT. Why would a current navigation node not be set?

`java.lang.IllegalStateException: no current navigation node`

**Simplified Code**

MainActivity

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.main_activity)

        setupToolbar()
        setupNavDrawer()
        setupNavigation()
    }


    private fun setupToolbar() {
        setSupportActionBar( toolbar )
    }

    private fun setupNavigation() {
        val navController = findNavController( R.id.nav_host_fragment)

        setupActionBarWithNavController( navController, main_activity_drawer_layout )
    }

    private fun setupNavDrawer() {
        val toggle = ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this,
                main_activity_drawer_layout,
                toolbar,
                R.string.navigation_drawer_open,
                R.string.navigation_drawer_close)

        main_activity_drawer_layout.addDrawerListener(toggle)
        toggle.syncState()


        nav_drawer.setNavigationItemSelectedListener {
            val navController = findNavController( R.id.nav_host_fragment )

            when (it.itemId) {
                R.id.nav_drawer_root_menu_item     -> navController.navigate(R.id.rootFragment)
                R.id.nav_drawer_first_menu_item    -> navController.navigate(R.id.action_rootFragment_to_firstFragment)
                R.id.nav_drawer_settings_menu_item -> navController.navigate(R.id.action_rootFragment_to_settingsFragment)
            }

            main_activity_drawer_layout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START)

            true
        }
    }

    override fun onSupportNavigateUp() = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment).navigateUp()
}
```

main_activity.xml

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_activity_drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <include
        layout="@layout/main_activity_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_drawer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_drawer_header"
        app:menu="@menu/nav_drawer_menu" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

nav_drawer_menu.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_drawer_root_menu_item"
        android:title="To Root" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_drawer_first_menu_item"
        android:title="To First" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_drawer_settings_menu_item"
        android:title="To Settings" />
</menu>
```

main_activity_content.xml

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

nav_graph.xml

```
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/nav_graph"
    app:startDestination="@id/rootFragment">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/rootFragment"
        android:name="app.anytune.navdrawertrials.RootFragment"
        android:label="root_fragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/root_fragment" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_rootFragment_to_firstFragment"
            app:destination="@id/firstFragment" />
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_rootFragment_to_settingsFragment"
            app:destination="@id/settingsFragment" />
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/firstFragment"
        android:name="app.anytune.navdrawertrials.FirstFragment"
        android:label="first_fragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/first_fragment" />
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/settingsFragment"
        android:name="app.anytune.navdrawertrials.SettingsFragment"
        android:label="settings_fragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/settings_fragment" />
</navigation>
```

root_fragment.xml (other nodes are similar empty fragments with just a label)

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".RootFragment">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="Root Fragment" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Do you know how to solve 2nd problem? `java.lang.IllegalStateException: no current navigation node` ?

Comment: Were you rotating the device when this error occurs?

Answer (score 3):

Regarding the first error, based on your code, when user select 'first' or 'settings' from drawer he is transferred to 'first' or 'settings' fragment using `action_rootFragment_to_firstFragment` or `action_rootFragment_to_settingsFragment` action, but if you try to select again 'first' or 'settings' from drawer there is no `action_rootFragment_to_firstFragment` or `action_rootFragment_to_settingsFragment` action inside `firstFragment` or `settingsFragment` element inside navigation graph.

The solution is to change:

```
when (it.itemId) { 
            R.id.nav_drawer_root_menu_item     -> navController.navigate(R.id.rootFragment) 
            R.id.nav_drawer_first_menu_item    -> navController.navigate(R.id.action_rootFragment_to_firstFragment) 
            R.id.nav_drawer_settings_menu_item -> navController.navigate(R.id.action_rootFragment_to_settingsFragment) 
        }
```

to:

```
   when (it.itemId) { 
            R.id.nav_drawer_root_menu_item     -> navController.navigate(R.id.rootFragment) 
            R.id.nav_drawer_first_menu_item    -> navController.navigate(R.id.firstFragment) 
            R.id.nav_drawer_settings_menu_item -> navController.navigate(R.id.settingsFragment) 
        }
```

The better solution is to tie destinations to menu-driven UI components(in your case drawer), change your menu items id to same as destinations id's, like this:

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/rootFragment"
    android:title="To Root" />
<item
    android:id="@+id/firstFragment"
    android:title="To First" />
<item
    android:id="@+id/settingsFragment"
    android:title="To Settings" />
```

and add

```
 setupWithNavController(nav_view, navController )
```

inside your main activity, instead of

```
nav_drawer.setNavigationItemSelectedListener {
        val navController = findNavController( R.id.nav_host_fragment )

        when (it.itemId) {
            R.id.nav_drawer_root_menu_item     -> navController.navigate(R.id.rootFragment)
            R.id.nav_drawer_first_menu_item    -> navController.navigate(R.id.action_rootFragment_to_firstFragment)
            R.id.nav_drawer_settings_menu_item -> navController.navigate(R.id.action_rootFragment_to_settingsFragment)
        }

        main_activity_drawer_layout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START)

        true
    }
```

Comment: This implies that the navController has a current state, and when calling `navController.navigate(R.id.action_to_something)` the navController must already be on the starting node where the action originates. Makes sense. It could also explain my second error, where I hadn't yet set the current state of the navController to the root node. I don't see how to set the current state to the root node though. I thought the Home node would automatically be assigned, but it didn't work for my other code base.

Comment: What is `setupWithNavController`?

Answer (score 0):

2) If the crash occurs on orientation change. Use the below on the activity
upgrade navigation version module to 2.2.0 or above

```
implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.2.0"
implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.2.0"
```